# Parsing a string to determine it's a website URL? (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, string, parsing

In ASP.net what's the best way I can parse a string to determine if it's a valid URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`Uri.TryCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131572.aspx).

For example:

```
Uri parsedUri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(input, UriKind.Absolute, out parsedUri)) {
    //Bad!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: Most regular expressions that you'll find will not fully conform to the URL spec. (eg, inline basic auth, `.museam`, full sets of domain name characters)

Comment: So why not sit down with the spec and write one that does?

Comment: Because you'll end up with an enormous and complicated regex (which you'll need to debug) that duplicates functionality already available in `Uri.TryCreate`.